# How to combine unicode-math font changing commands?

Tags: unicode-math

I would like to be able to combine font changing commands using `unicode-math` in a math environment. For instance, I define a symbol as being in an upright font, but I want a bold version of that upright symbol. I was thinking that `\symbf{\symup{V}}` would work, but it does not. There are the commands `\symbfup` and others to specify both font faces. How can I accomplish combining them? The actual use case is shown in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\newcommand*{\velocity}{\symup{V}}
\newcommand*{\vectorsym}[1]{\symbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\velocity \quad \vectorsym{\velocity} \quad \symbfup{V}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex math font commands (both classical and unicode-math) are designed not to merge in this way, the intention is that you have a named command for each alphabet used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I need to define a special command to do what I want? OK that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: I did have some thoughts about making the math font commands behave more like the text font ones so that `\mathbf{\mathsf{X}}` would give you a bold sans X. Maybe if I get some time to look at the code again over the Christmas break…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As David Carlisle remarks in comments, math alphabet commands have never thought to behave “cumulatively”. Thus `\symbf` has no effect on something already affected by `\symup`. However, since your aim is to produce `\symbf` anyway (and `\symbfup` does nothing different from it), you can define `\vectorsym` to locally redefine `\symup` to be a no-op:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\newcommand*{\velocity}{\symup{V}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vectorsym}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \symup \use:n
  \symbf{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\velocity \quad \vectorsym{\velocity} \quad \symbfup{V} \quad \vectorsym{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So the bold font makes things upright anyways? Then how would I achieve a bold italic math font? Do those characters have to exist in the font? I'm not sure what a use case for that would be, but now I'm curious :-)

Comment: @darthbith `\symbfit`, IIRC

Comment: Well that's just too logical... thank you again! :-)